# Proof Verification.Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

This is a proof verification. Im afraid i  maybe missed something (mostly from a number theorytic point of view) and didnt notice there might be more cases than i thought of.Or maybe used a circular argument or something.Also there might be easier proofs for this problem  im not looking for something like that.(You are welcomed to write them but they wont count as an answer) .Also i might written unnecessary arguments in relation with the approach of this proof.Not in relation with some other smaller proof.If the proof is wrong  you are welcomed to point why and where it is wrong and lead the correct way.

$\textbf {PROBLEM}$:

If $G$ is of order $p^{n}$ where $p$ is prime.Then every subgroup of order $|H|=p^{n-1}$ is normal.

$ \textbf {PROOF}$: I know there exists $\phi$ homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow S_p$ with $ker(\phi) < H$.(actually it is the group action of $G$ to the set $G/H$ of left cosets of H)

Now  i know  $$|G|=[G:ker\phi]|ker\phi|$$ 
I also know that  $[G:ker\phi]=|G/ker\phi|=|\phi(G)|$.

Now $|\phi(G)| \mid |S_p|$ $\Rightarrow $ $$|\phi(G)| \mid 1\cdot2\cdot 3...\cdot p$$.

Now i also have $|ker\phi| \mid |H| \Rightarrow |ker\phi| \mid p^{n-1} |$ so Let $|ker\phi|=p^{k}$ where   $k<n-1$.

SO from the
$|G|=[G:ker\phi]|kerg|$ i get $$p^{n}=a\cdot p^{k} \Rightarrow p^{L}=a $$ where $L \geq 2$ . That cant be since  then $$p^{L} \mid (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot ....p) \Rightarrow p^{L-1} \mid (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot ....p-1)$$ which is obviously a contradiction.So $$|ker\phi|=p^{n-1}$$ and since $ker\phi$ is a subgroup of $H$ with the same order they are equal and it is known that the kernel is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your argument is the right idea, but it could be stated more succinctly.

You established that $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ is contained in $H$ (indeed, $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ is the [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)) of $H$), hence $|\operatorname{ker}(\phi)| \leq p^{n-1}$. Since $|G| = p^n = |\phi(G)| |\operatorname{ker}(\phi)|$, this means that $|\phi(G)| \geq p$. But $|\phi(G)|$ divides $p!$, and the highest power of $p$ dividing $p!$ is $p$, so this forces $|\phi(G)| = p$, hence $|\operatorname{ker}(\phi)| = p^{n-1}$. Therefore $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ must be all of $H$, hence $H$ is a kernel of a homomorphism, hence $H$ is normal.